# What is the purpose of this return value?

Tags: c, multithreading

I ran into some code I couldn't find an answer to on Google or SO. I am looking at a thread function which returns void* as you could expect. However, before the thread function ends it suddenly pulls this stunt,

```
return (void*) 0;
```

What is the purpose of that? I can't make any sense of it.

edit:

After understanding this is the same as NULL-- it is my thought they used this to skip including stdlib.

Comment: It's just the same as `return NULL;` - why is that a problem ? Maybe you should post more of the code ?

Comment: I had never seen that done before-- is it really that common?

Comment: Sure - why not ? Maybe there are one or more return statements earlier in the function which return a non-NULL pointer ? We won't know unless you post more code...

Comment: The only sense I can make is they didn't want to include stdlib where NULL is defined? There are no other returns in the thread.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to read more peoples' code because I was clueless about this. I need to see how others code so I don't get too stuck in my style.

Comment: Another possible explanation that I can think of besides not including stdlib.h is that the return value when joining the thread should be interpreted as an int, and the void* will be casted to int on join. Another thread, or another point of return, might return (void*)1 or (void*)2, etc. Casting thus eliminates the compiler warning and returning NULL might be confusing in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. :)

Comment: Can't believe nobody's mentioned nullptr and C++0x yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(void*)0` is the null pointer, a.k.a. `NULL` (which actually is a macro defined in several header files, e.g. `stddef.h` or `stdio.h`, that basically amounts to the same thing as `(void*)0`).

**Update:**

How to explain null pointers and their usefulness? Basically, it's a special value that says, "This pointer doesn't point anywhere," or, "This pointer is not set to a valid object reference."

Historical note: Tony Hoare, who is said to have invented null references in 1965, is known to regret that invention and thus calls it his ["Billion Dollar Mistake"](http://qconlondon.com/london-2009/presentation/Null+References%3a+The+Billion+Dollar+Mistake):

Whenever you work with pointers, you must make sure to never dereference a null pointer (because it doesn't reference anything by definition). If you do it anyway, you'll either get abnormal program termination, a general protection fault, or unexpected program behaviour at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have not encountered any C++ compiler saying `NULL` or `0` cannot be converted to `void*` (or to/from `int*`, for example). But there might be some smart compilers or static-analysis tools that would report `0 to void-pointer` conversion as a warning.

That statement is commonly found in callback implementation (like a thread-routine), which must adhere to prototype of callback being demanded (`pthread_create`, `CreateThread` etc). Therefore, when you implement that function, you must return the same type it was demanded for. For `pthread_create` *routine*, you must return a `void*` - and that's why `return (void*)0;` is there.